# Java button to open URL on chrome browser

Tags: java, swing, google-chrome, url, jbutton

I'm trying to open a certain `URL` on Chrome upon button click in Java. But I'm not quite sure how. All the answers I found online is using the PC's default browser (Internet Explorer, most times).

How would it be done if I want the URL to be opened on Google Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Selenium Web Driver for that. (https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/chrome/ChromeDriver.html). But you shouldn't forget about the case when Chrome isn't installed on clients PC.

Comment: Thank you. I'll give this a try. Does this also include opening the chrome app as it redirect to the given url? Or do I have to manually write the code for the opening of the application? Sorry for the trouble and thank you for helping me out. I'm Still learning.

Comment: *"But you shouldn't forget about the case when Chrome isn't installed on clients PC."* Indeed! I for one, have always had Chrome installed, but for about a year, it just .. failed to launch. Don't torture the end user! And if you are the only user of this software, make Chrome the default browser and be done with it! There is *no* good case here for using anything other that the methodology for opening the user's ***default browser.***